# How to setup search scope within location and frameworks in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9-beta, xcode9

In Xcode 8 setup of new search scope within location and frameworks was very easy:
[image]

This functionality is extremely useful for search within all linked frameworks. I often use it, for example, to find error name by code.

But I'm confused with new XCode 9 UI:
[image]

How can I achieve the same functionality in Xcode 9?

Comment: In beta 3, they have updated the search interface again, so it seems they are actively working on the feature. Let's hope they add this ability back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated for Xcode 9 beta 3.

I don't think this achieves the same exact functionality, but it is close:

[image]